# RegEx JavaScript to replace equal sign followed by a new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to craft a regex expression that will replace equal sign followed by a new line with nothing.

Here is an example of the text.  Notice each line ends with equals and a new line.

```html
<p style=3D"border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; padding-bottom: 10px; margi=
n-bottom: 10px">From @mytwitterrrr filtered:<br></p><div><div><a href=3D"ht=
tps://feeder.co/p/076b2f56-af6c-11eb-adf3-1a21cf3a468a?u=3Da6566144-b0a5-4d=
```

I am fairly sure this code is replacing new lines and all equal sign occurrences including the one at the beginning of the first line <p style=3D".  I just need to replace the equal signs that at the end of each line.

```
let parsed = message.replace(/\n*.+=/g,',')
```

Thank you!

Comment: first you convert `=3D` into something unique, like `@@@`. Then you get rid of all `=` replacing them with \''\. And finally you reconvert all `@@@` to `=`

Comment: You are looking at [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) text encoding. There are existing npm packages for it, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/quoted-printable. Better to use the appropriate encoder/decoder than trying to hack it somewhat with regular expressions.

Comment: `message.replace(/=$/gm, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work

```
/=\n/g, ''
```

```js
const currentString = `<p style=3D"border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; padding-bottom: 10px; margi=
n-bottom: 10px">From @sl_steamroom filtered:<br></p><div><div><a href=3D"ht=
tps://feeder.co/p/076b2f56-af6c-11eb-adf3-1a21cf3a468a?u=3Da6566144-b0a5-4d=
`
const newStr = currentString.replace(/=\n/g, '');

document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML = newStr
console.log(newStr)
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Owen Kelvin, this is working perfectly for my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will replace each `=` that is followed by a newline, but will not replace the new line character.

```
let parsed = message.replace(/=(?=\n)/g,',')
```

It does so by using a look-ahead `(?=\n)` which looks ahead for the newline `\n` character.

Comment: Layton GB, this works great with a second replace to replace the newline character. Thank you!